# Why is os.path.abspath adding the alias name when it expands an alias?

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

My code needs to be able to search through a list of directories for a specific file. It needs to handle an alias as part of a path name and still find the actual path to a file. For example, it needs to turn something like `$HOME/test.dat` into `/home/greenmatt/test.dat`. As such, I'm trying to use `os.path.abspath`.

Unfortunately, the results come back with the alias name glued onto the end of the actual directory name. The following demonstrates what I'm seeing.

From the command line:

```
> echo $HOME
/home/greenmatt
```

Then inside Python:

```
> python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Apr 29 2018, 16:14:56) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print(os.path.abspath('$HOME'))
/home/greenmatt/$HOME
```

`os.path.realpath` does the same thing:

```
>>> print(os.path.realpath('$HOME'))
/home/greenmatt/$HOME
```

Why is the extra '$HOME' getting added to the path? How do I get the absolute path without it?

Comment: You need `os.path.expandvars`

Comment: @MichaelButscher: That worked, if you type it up as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.path.expandvars(path)` expands environment variables in a path. After expanding, the absolute path can be created. Together:

```
os.path.abspath(os.path.expandvars(path))
```

Answer (score 1):

`HOME` is a shell variable, and `abspath` doesn't use the shell at all, so the parameter isn't expanded. As a result, it's treated as a literal string naming a subdirectory in your current directory. You have to expand it yourself. Since `HOME` is a standard environment variable, you can use `os.getenv`.

```
> os.path.abspath(os.getenv('HOME'))  # $ must be omitted
/home/greenmatt
```

(Of course, if it *wasn't* an environment variable, you couldn't access it at all, even if it was defined in the shell from which you started Python.)

---

Consider this an explanation of why your original attempt didn't work. In practice, use [`expandvars` as suggested by Michael Butscher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53283599/1126841).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd thought of doing that, but given the sort of inputs I'll be getting, it would be onerous to extract the environment variable name out of the path, get its value, and then join everything back together.

Comment: I had forgotten about `expandvars`; definitely a simpler way to go.